# django views - accessing a m2m field in a generic view

Tags: django, view, generics, m2m

I've stumbled upon this issue and my noob brain got fried trying to resolve it. I feel like there's some basic concepts here that I'm missing.

So I have this "Films" model with category choice field and a m2m relationship to a "Directors" model, and I'm trying to write 2 different views, one that returns a list of films filtered by category and one that returns a list of films filtered by director. 
The first one is easy, but I just don't know how to get the director model's name field to create the second filter.

So I have this models (i've taken the irrelevant stuff out including the category thing i mentioned above)

```
class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    web = models.URLField(blank=True, help_text= "opcional")


class Film(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 15)
    director = models.ManyToManyField(Director, blank=True, help_text= "opcional")
```

this url

```
(r'^peliculas/director/(?P<director>\w+)/$', 'filtered_by_director'),
```

and this view

```
def filtered_by_director(request,director):
    return list_detail.object_list(
        request, 
        queryset = Film.objects.filter(director.name=director),
        template_name ='sections/film_list.html',
        template_object_name = 'film',
        paginate_by = 3

        )
```

The same template is supposed to be used by both views to render the relevant list of objects
The view doesn't like the filter i'm using at the queryset for the m2m field, but I have no clue how to do it really, I've tried whatever I could think of and it gives me a "keyword can't be an expression" error

Any help to this lowly noob will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line `queryset = Film.objects.filter(director.name=director),`

needs to read: `queryset = Film.objects.filter(director__name=director),`

Field lookups are done by `__` double underscore syntax:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Answer (score 0):

In your filter, try specifying the director name like ([documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#s-lookups-that-span-relationships)):

`filter(director__name=director)`